# gcc flag to force use of predefined macros

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, clang, mips

My problem is following. I'm trying to build a project for mips.
And when I download it from it's repository, there is no problem building it, but when I build it when it is a part of a larger project, I receive a folowing error:

> error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant

I found out that it is a problem because some variable is called mips whereas the same variable is defined as predefined macro in gcc compiler.

```
#define mips 1
```

I verified it with:

> mipsel-linux-gnu-g++ -dM -E - < /dev/null

So, my question is, does any body know is there a certain compiler flag or whatever, that forces the use of this macro? It is strange that there is no build problem when I download the same code from repository.

Both projects are build with the same toolchain, I already verified that.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wouldn't forcing `mips` to be defined possibly have unintended side effects, when the code always believes that it's being compiled for mips? Anyway, I checked and `-dM -E` lists macros `unix` and `linux` on my system, yet they weren't defined when I compiled a program. I suggest that you check that there isn't any header files that define the macro and that it isn't defined as a compiler argument.

Comment: I'm not forcing anything, I just want to find out why this is happening. When you check mips toolchain, that #define mips 1 exists. And because of some flags or something, I have a problem with my structure in code which I called mips. Compiler reports the error I posted. I just want to know is there any flag that suppresses this define or forces it.

Comment: Ah, if you're using it just for debugging the compilation, then it's not a problem. MSalters seems to know the answer. I have never compiled without `-ansi` or any non-official `-std`, which explains my test results and probably yours as well.

Comment: `-std=c..` is good, you could also try `-Umips`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["When the -ansi option, or any -std option that requests strict conformance, is given to the compiler, all the system-specific predefined macros outside the reserved namespace are suppressed. The parallel macros, inside the reserved namespace, remain defined."](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-specific-Predefined-Macros.html#System-specific-Predefined-Macros)

That is to say, with `--ansi` you still get `__mips__` but not `mips`.

Comment: Thanks! This was the right answer. The project on which the mips was not suppressed used std=gnu++11. I knew there was something with these options, but I didn't know how to search it. Thanks once again.